# How can I exclude child class from click event?

Tags: jquery, children

I want to exclude the class `noclick` from the click function:

```js
$( ".click" ).on( "click", ":not(.noclick *)", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

```css
.noclick{
  background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="click">
    <th>Click</th>
    <th>Click</th>
    <th class="noclick">Nothing should happen here</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Remove that asterisk from the :not(.noclick)

Comment: It will work, I've tested.

Comment: @Phiter Yes, this worked!

Comment: @Phiter: why not post it as answer.

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".click *:not(.noclick)", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar just did. I usually like to comment first and then answer

Comment: Its better to post as an answer if you are sure about it. what if someone else post the same answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply remove the asterisk from `":not(.noclick *)"`

This makes it so events on `.noclick`'s descendants don't trigger the function, but doesn't prevent `.noclick` itself.

```js
$( ".click" ).on( "click", ":not(.noclick)", function() {
  console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

```css
.noclick{
background-color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="click">
    <th>Click</th>
    <th>Click</th>
    <th class="noclick">Nothing should happen here</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: One question, How would I write the exclusion if I had this function `$(document).off("click", ".click").on("click", ".click", function (event) {`

Comment: `$(document).off("click", ".click").on("click", ".click :not(.noclick)", function (event) {`

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand

Answer (score 0):

This will also work for dynamically added `tr.click`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".click *:not(.noclick)", function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.noclick {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr class="click">
    <th>Click</th>
    <th>Click</th>
    <th class="noclick">Nothing should happen here</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code should work.

```
$( ".click" ).on( "click", function() {
  if ($( this ).has( ".noclick" ).length == 0)
      console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Comment: `$( ".click" ).on( "click", function(e) {
  if (! $(e.target).hasClass("noclick"))
      console.log($(this).text());
});` would work.

Comment: Please explain a bit more. As it is this is just a piece of code and no answer.